# Surveillance mobile robot using WiFi and android phone as the controller

Tags: android, wifi

I have a project on constructing a surveillance mobile robot using Wireless Fidelity. Is it possible to use IP camera using wireless router without using a web browser and directly controlled using android phone? The app contains the live streaming and the controller.

Comment: your question is too vague. lots of things are "possible" so it isn't clear what your question is trying to acheive or what steps you've already taken (if any).

Comment: We don't have enough knowledge regarding that. We know that using an ip camera it needs a browser to see the video but we would like to know if it is possible to use an IP camera without using a web browser instead the video of the camera will be pass directly to the android phone using a router?

Answer (score 0):

yes you just need the android phone to be connected to the same router. This also depends on the IP camera but it can be done without a browser.

EDIT: actually the router could potentially route the packet to the phone via a server setup remotely but i am assuming that you are not going to dive so deep.

Comment: how can it be possible? what do you mean via a server setup? is it about to configure the router?